# default arg with test class member variable

Tags: python, pytest

Have the simplified script snippet as follows:

```
#!pytest
import pytest

class TestDefaultArg():
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
    def setup_cleanup(self, request):
        request.cls.default_id = 100
        yield

    def test_basic(self):
        self.db_helper()

    def db_helper(self, id=self.default_id):
        pass
```

The intention is to pass the class memeber self.default_id to db_helper(). However, it gives me this error:

```
/u/qxu/test.py:4: in <module>
    class TestDefaultArg():
/u/qxu/test.py:13: in TestDefaultArg
    def db_helper(self, id=self.default_id):
E   NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

So, the question is, how to use a test class data member to provide the default argument for a test class member function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to `pytest`, but just to normal Python functionality.
You cannot reference `self` in a default argument, because the default argument is created at load time, not at run time. Also, you have been creating a class variable, not an instance variable, so you have to access it using `self.__class__` instead of `self`.

The usual way to handle this is to use a `None` default value and only set the value in the function, e.g. something like:

```py
    def db_helper(self, current_id=None):
        if current_id is None:
            current_id = self.__class__.default_id
        print(current_id)
```

Note that I have also changed the variable name, as `id` is a built-in name, and it is not good practice to shadow these.

*EDIT*: Use check for `None` as proposed by @chepner.

Comment: This fails if a non-`None` falsey value is a valid ID. Being explicit with `current_id = current_id if current_id is None else self.__class__.default_id` would be better, and a simple `if` statement like `if current_id is None: current_id = self.__class__.default_id` would be best.

Comment: @chepner - you are right, I have been sloppy here... will correct it.